# Can a taxonomy vocabulary entity be disabled or unpublished?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

Vocabularies are config entities. I can see the delete link in the UI. 
In the example vocabulary config yml -

taxonomy.vocabulary.blah.yml -

```
uuid: 16ebbc47-16ac-461c-0000-00000000
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
name: 'Blah'
vid: blah
description: 'blahblah'
hierarchy: 0
weight: 0
```

There is a `status` property which is `true` by default. I tried changing this to `false` and imported the configs, but sadly the vocabulary still lists on the '/structure/taxonomy' page.

Is it possible to make a vocabulary entity disable ?

My use-case is to create a Migration plugin which deletes/ disables the existing vocabulary entities. Not sure how to achieve this, is there any existing migrate plugin which deletes the destination entity ?

Open for any other suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Rabbit Hole might fit the bill: https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jasonflaherty ,but the module acts on the page display. I wouldn't want the vocabs to show on admin side - 'structure/taxonomy' path.